# failed to update ssl context in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl

Im using flutter presence, then waiting verification email after user input, but i got announcement in debugin

```
w/firestore( 5319): (24.7.0) [grpccallprovider]: failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.googleplayservicesnotavailableexception
```

thanks and regards for any help.

Comment: **I've got the answer, re-build the simulator that has googleplaystore, then the problem is solved**